# WordPress page is also a directory

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, permalinks

I've got a WordPress page where the permalink is `/foo`.

I'm hoping to add a new HTML page (non-WP) at `/foo/bar`, but when I created that folder via FTP, obviously the original `/foo` page started showing an empty directory, instead of the old WP page.

Is there any way of combining the two, so the index of `/foo` is the WordPress page and the index of `/foo/bar` is a non-WP HTML page?

Many thanks!

Comment: To have static html out of wordpress, you need to place that folder where your `wp-content` folder is, and the permalink structure must be different from anything you can use in your wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP request first resolve the folder which you placed inside your WordPress installation. So there is no direct way to achieve this becuase  your sub-folder name is same as the page URL.

You need to rename your folder-name/page permalink to make this happen.

Here is some suggestions,

1. [WP Page and Subdirectory with same name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name)
2. [Page URL not working due to physical directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26554/page-url-not-working-due-to-physical-directory)

Also please ask WordPress related question here: [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Sorry, I didn't realise there was a WP Stack Exchange - thanks for the heads-up & useful links!